# How to get Android Material TextInputLayout startIcon View?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

Is there a way to get a reference to the Android Material Library `TextInputLayout` `startIcon`'s `View`? `TextInputLayout.startIconDrawable` only gets the `Drawable`, not the `View`. I'm trying to animate this `View`, so I need a reference. Here's an example below, I would like a View reference to the heart icon.

[image]

Comment: you can always make a custom layout. please share some image so that i can understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Sure, I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `startIcon` of the `TextInputLayout` using its resource identifier name to get the resource integer id using [`getIdentifer()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) of the [`Resources`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources) class.

The identifier name of the `TextInputLayout` is **`text_input_start_icon`**

To get the id of `startIcon`:

**Kotlin**

```
val startIconViewId = resources.getIdentifier("text_input_start_icon", "id", packageName)
```

**Java**

```
int startIconViewId = getResources().getIdentifier("text_input_start_icon", "id", getPackageName());
```

And to get the view itself (which is [`CheckableImageButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/CheckableImageButton.java)) to make your animation:

**Kotlin**

```
val textInputLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.my_text_input_layout)
val startIcon: CheckableImageButton = textInputLayout.findViewById(startIconViewId)
```

**Java**

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_text_input_layout);
CheckableImageButton startIcon = textInputLayout.findViewById(startIconViewId);
```

Note: To use this procedure you must set `app:startIconDrawable` in `TextInputLayout` in your layout.

Demo of my test:

[image]